# C# .NET DLL files and using them in a .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll

I Inherited a C# web application project from previous developers and they left no documentation for me other than code comments, and it has been taking me some time figure out what they previously did.

So I found the class files .cs files they are using in the project in our team services (TFS) source control and one of the changes I have to implement is in one of the class files. However I could not find any of these .cs files on the production server.

I found out later what they did was create a Class Library DLL file and added it to the web application on production, and that is why I did not find the class files on production, they are in the DLL file.

I see the instructions for creating a new Class Library DLL, it is straightforward. My question is once I make my changes to the class, can I just create a new DLL file and swap it into the project to replace the previous DLL?, and if there is an error swap it back?

Or is there more work than that involved?

The previous developers were not using a development server, and also the source control does not match the production application and cannot be linked to the production server, and it is going to take me a lot of work to make a development server, so for now I have to make the changes directly to the production site.

Comment: Honestly first priority would be setting up a dev environment. And tons and tons of personal CYA if politick didn't let that happen. I don't envy you

Comment: Some developers create DLLs when they are not necessarily.  Perhaps, you can just add the source files to the project.  It's a lot simpler.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  At points you make it sound like they have source code on the Production Server; other times just the .dlls.  Regardless, you want to work off your DEV environment with source control. To obtain the missing source code off production, consider using _Redgate Reflector_ or _JetBrains dotPeek_ to reverse engineer the source code and commit it to TFS quick smart.

Answer (score 0):

> *So I found the class files .cs files they are using in the project in our team services (TFS) source control and one of the changes I have to implement is in one of the class files. However I could not find any of these .cs files on the production server.*

- That would be **standard/normal**
- You'd only be looking for *source* files (`.cs` or `.vb`) in deployed/production  if the application/web site wasn't `pre-compliled` (in a dll or set of dlls), otherwise no *source code* will be present. Typically, source files will only be in source control (TFS/Git/etc) and/or in your local dev box.

> *once I make my changes to the class, can I just create a new DLL file and swap it into the project to replace the previous DLL?, and if there is an error swap it back?*

- why don't you first clone (aka "Get Latest") from TFS and debug locally?
- Then you can *compile* the application and figure out what dll/s should be updated

On that note, it is *possible* to just overwrite the *updated/affected* dlls (by code changes). And yes, it too, is possible to "roll back dlls" by saving (aka "backup") the "old" dlls that you will be replacing with new ones.

I'd take extra care of other dependencies though - no idea how large your application is nor how much interconnected dependencies it has. If you're updating some *external libraries* be sure to test - sometimes dependencies are to a *specific* version

Obviously, not all changes are in compiled dlls (e.g. front end, scripts, data, etc.) so you'll have to figure out exactly what could be affected, test, debug and have a rollback plan....

> *The previous developers were not using a development server, and the source control does not match the production application*

- Their local dev boxes were probably the "dev environment" which is entirely doable
- To what extent...an image or text here or there might be "ok" (you'll have to know if those things are static or dynamically generated/rendered). That would likely be extent of your task - re: to sync local, source control and production from this point forward...

---

**If** at all possible:

- Download your production site to your local box and run it from your local box.
- "Push" your changes to your local copy and see what happens.

While this sounds "extreme" (if you have a large application), you may find it easier to do "diff" between folders *locally* (so even images/etc. can be "diffed").

Hth...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to confirm that DLL files are swappable in applications as long as the reference was previously created, I believe I am going to try to create a development server using a copy of our production site like was suggested.

Comment: Part of the problem here is hat we are using Microsoft Azure for our hosting, but unfortunately the previous developers did not take advantage of all the automatic features of Azure that make it easy to use, they instead used it like a normal web host, instead of a cloud provider. Our main web application is on an Azure VM but it is just a normal web application, it was not created as an Azure Cloud Service in Visual Studio like it should have been.

Comment: @MichaelG.Workman - understood. _Perhaps_ the intent was to have "private" instances (full control)? Best ~